# SVM applied in images using Julia Language

Tags: math, julia, svm

I would like to create programming involving a support vector machine (SVM) in Julia with scikit-Learn of Python.

So I need a training set `(X_train)` and a test set `(y_train)`.

As an example, I have an `X` set of type 500 x 3 (this is my full data).

Hence, I get a subset `A` of `X` of type Array 110 x 3 and a subset `B` of `X` of type Array 120 x 3.
The union of sets `A` and `B` will be my `X_train` training set.

My `y_train` set is obtained as follows:

For every vector element of `A`, I associate with the number `0` and for every vector element of `B`, I associate with the number `1`.

So I have the following training and exit set:

`T = {(a1, 0), (a2, 0), ..., (a110,0), (b1, 1), (b2, 1), ..., (b120, 1)}.`

These sets `A` and `B` are disjoint and obtained from an RGB img vector image that I transformed into `X` of the 500 x 3 array type.

After having the `T` set, I should use Python's scikitlearn library in Julia, the `svc.fit()` command and probably the `svc.predict()` command to create a prediction model for the remaining pixels that have not been trained.

Could someone help me make this code?

I am not able to associate every element from `A` to `0` and every element from `B` to `1`.

To concatenate I am using `vcat(A, B)` and defining `X_train = vcat(A, B)`.

I've tried many things and I can't get out of here.

**In summary:**

I have an X set of vectors in 3 coordinates. And I would like to associate a numerical value between 0 and 1 for each X vector. So I took a part of the X set as the X_train training set. This X_train set is the union of two disjoint subsets A and B in which for each vector of A I know that y is 0 and for each vector of B I know that y is 1.
I would now like to train the X_train set and get a y function that gives me a value between 0 to 1 of the whole X set. This via SVM. I believe that there are many other supervised approaches, but with that I can follow.